# extract specific text from data

Tags: c#

I have below text and I want to extract Comment allez-vous from below text how do I extract using C# ?. This text will be different all the time. rest of the data format is the same.

```
handleResponse({
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "Comment allez-vous"
   }
  ]
 }
}
);
```

Comment: Need some more information; Specifically, can the 'comment' text include a double quote itself? If so, how is it escaped? This question can't really be correctly answered without knowing that.

Comment: Yes, you need to provide some information about how much this input could vary. If it will always be exactly like this, you could just determine the offset to the first character you want. But I strongly suspect other parts can vary.

Comment: NO Comment text does not includes double quote. I like to have text without the Quote. Also Except the  text in double qoute seciont of "Comment allez-vous" will be the same.

Comment: Look at those braces! Is this LISP or C#?

Answer (score 3):

It's JSON. Use a JSON parser for .Net like JSON.NET or the JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: DUH! I'm sitting here looking at it, and that should have been obvious. (That answers the question about format!)

Answer (score 0):

1. Look for last index of ". index A
2. Find first index for translatedText + length of translatedText +1. index B
3. fetch all string betwee B and A.